# Check value of cell with column and return sum of values of previous column for which the values are same

Tags: excel

After checking if a cell value exists in a column, I need to get the sum of all the values of the cell next to the matching cell. For instance, I check if the value in cell A1 exists in column B, and assuming it matches B5,B7 and B9 then I want the sum of values in cell C5,C7 and C9.

Comment: Is this question about Excel or about some other spreadsheet software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you use Microsoft Excel you have to use [SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx) function:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B9,A1,C1:C9)
```

Of course, according to your language version and regional settings above function can have localized name and instead of commas there might be semicolons required.